# How can we get the JobId in the RetryContext?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-retry

I am just extending my this question here - [Spring Retry doesn't works when we use RetryTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115536/spring-retry-doesnt-works-when-we-use-retrytemplate).

How can we get the `JobId` in the `RetryContext` ?

I went through link: [Spring Batch how to configure retry period for failed jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128067/spring-batch-how-to-configure-retry-period-for-failed-jobs), but still did not know.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RecoveryCallback implements RecoveryCallback<String>{
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private AbcService abcService;
    
    @Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}")
    private Long jobId;
        
    @Override
    public String recover(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
        log.warn("RecoveryCallback | recover is executed ...");
        
        ErrorLog errorLog = ErrorLog.builder()
                .jobName("ABC")
                .stepName("RETRY_STEP")
                .stepType("RETRY")
                ....
                ....
                ....
                .jobId(jobId)
                .build();
        abcService.updateErrLog(errorLog);
        
        return "Batch Job Retried and exausted with all attemps";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are injecting `stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId` in a field of a Spring bean, you need to make this bean `Step` scoped. With this approach, the RetryContext is not used.

If you want to use the retry context, then you need to put the jobId in the context in the retryable method first. From your linked question:

```
retryTemplate.execute(retryContext  -> {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(sampleAcctJob, pdfParams);
        if(!jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions().isEmpty()) {
            log.error("============== sampleAcctJob Job failed, retrying.... ================");
            throw jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions().iterator().next();
        }
        logDetails(jobExecution);
        // PUT JOB ID in retryContext
        retryContext.setAttribute("jobId", jobExecution.getExecutionId());
        return jobExecution;
    });
```

With that, you can get the jobId from the context in the `recover` method:

```
@Override
public String recover(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
    log.warn("RecoveryCallback | recover is executed ...");
    
    ErrorLog errorLog = ErrorLog.builder()
            .jobName("ABC")
            .stepName("RETRY_STEP")
            .stepType("RETRY")
            ....
            ....
            .jobId(context.getAttribute("jobId"))
            .build();
    abcService.updateErrLog(errorLog);
    
    return "Batch Job Retried and exausted with all attemps";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding StepScope etc and I was getting error proxyScope etc.. I dont have a way to get the JobId here it seem. Could you please suggest further ?

Comment: You can use the second approach by putting  the jobId in the context in the retryable method (`context.setAttribute("jobId", jobExecution.getExecutionId());`) and get access it in the recover method (`.jobId(context.getAttribute("jobId"))`).

Comment: Thanks, checking that, `jobExecution.getJobId()` is the correct way to get JobId ?

Comment: `JobExecution.getJobId()` returns the job instance id. `jobExecution.getExecutionId()` that I used in the answer returns the job execution Id. Use the one that you need according to your requirement.